# WinRT CaliburnMicro event binding to ListPickerFlyout

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro, flyout

The event binding of Caliburn.Micro seems not to work with the *ListPickerFlyout* of Windows Phone 8.1. I want to bind the event *ItemsPicked* of the Flyout to the corresponding method of my ViewModel.

```
    <ListView 
            x:Name="Links"
            toolkitex:ListViewExtensions.BindableSelection="{Binding Selection}"
            cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemClick] = [Click($link)]">

        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <ListPickerFlyout 
                SelectionMode="Single"
                Placement="Full"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ctrls:FlyoutEx.Parent="{Binding ElementName=Links}"
                ctrls:FlyoutEx.IsOpen="{Binding IsListSelectionOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                cm:Message.Attach="[Event ItemsPicked] = [ItemsPicked($this, $eventArgs)]">
            </ListPickerFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    </ListView>
```

When the event will be raised, I get the following exception: *No target found for method ItemsPicked.*

> System.Exception: No target found for method ItemsPicked.
>          at Caliburn.Micro.ActionMessage.Invoke(Object eventArgs)
>          at Caliburn.Micro.TriggerAction`1.Execute(Object sender, Object parameter)
>          at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender,
>   ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
>          at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior.OnEvent(Object
>   sender, Object eventArgs)

I also tried it without event and method method parameters but it does not work either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just get the "SelectedItems" property?  Assuming the control does the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot handle into the events Opened or Closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured becouse ListPickerFlyout doesn't have DataContext (or has wrong). I don't see a way to set the DataContext, but you can determine selected item by pinning to setter of your `SelectedList` property from ViewModel. For example if your `SelectedList` is type of `string`:

```
    private string _selectedLists;
    public string SelectedLists
    {
        get { return _selectedLists; }
        set
        {
            _selectedLists = value;

            ItemsPicked(value); // <----------------

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedLists);
        }
    }

    private void ItemsPicked(string selectedValue)
    {
        //Handle selection
    }
```

Comment: Datacontext is inherited from the object from which its attached.  FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout or `<Button><Button.Flyout> ... </Button.Flyout></Button>` as an example... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308515.aspx

Comment: While it is part of the problem not knowing how he setup the ListPickerFlyout to begin with from a coding standing point it shouldn't be a allowed to free stand on the screen since it is a Flyout, has to be attached in some fashion.  We don't have the whole picture in this instance presently.

Comment: The ListPickerFlyout is attachted a ListView control.